# Possible attack on the ssh server

Tags: ssh, security

could be anybody so nice explain me.
On my linux server in log auth.log, i've found next line:

```
Jul 27 09:16:30 aws-ftp sshd[13186]: Bad protocol version identification 'telnet mail.softlution.com 2222' from 194.120.221.212 port 63085
```

google gave me this link:

```
https://scottlinux.com/2012/03/07/troubleshooting-ssh-server-logs-and-error-messages/
```

example 6, but in this message domain telnet mail.softlution.com is not my domain and the IP 194.120.221.212 - not my ip.

What can it be?
Thx in advance!

Comment: I have fail2ban, autorization on ssh only with key and from specific ip - thats all i've already done. But why on my server i see possible connection from 194.120.221.212 to not my domain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a German IP address. Honestly, it's *very* common to see scanners out there on the Internet scanning for open ports and potential vulnerabilities. If you're concerned, you can use a host-based firewall, only allow SSH keys, use fail2ban, etc. to minimize risk.

Just a guess as to what they're trying to do...

Given that the port the bad actor is trying to connect back to is 2222 and this looks conveniently like the SSH port (22), it appears they're trying to see if they can execute a command on your box to establish a connection back home.

Answer (score 0):

It is not amazons IP either, so it is most likely just some bot.

You can setup fail2ban on your server and configure it so parse ssh logs.
There are great examples right in config file, so you'll just need to change some lines to fit your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to secure your server really good you can setup a Mailserver on it, which notifys you every time if someone tries to login. You can also set the default SSH Port on an high-level Port with random numbers, Fail2Ban, 2-Factor-Authentication, SSH Key with a phasprase and maybe if you have a private VPN Server or a static IP a whitelist for logins.

There is a workaround to get notifications with the Comunicationtool Slack, if you want to get help, they are multiple Workarounds here on the StackExchange Network and on Google